# Jquery mobile load page function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have  2 pages in jquery mobile html code. I want when the school page is loaded it should display an alert

HEADER PART

```
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="custom/scripts/new.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript">
```

This is the pages code

```
div data-role="page" id="indexpage" data-theme="e">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>S-Select</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<div class="row">

  <a href="#schoolpage" data-transition="flip" id="school">Schools</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="schoolpage" data-theme="e">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="e" data-position="fixed">
  <a href="#indexpage" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
  <div data-role="content">
  school page

   </div>
```

I also have a javascript code that should show the alert when schoolpage is loaded after the click of school button(#school) in the index page
The script is saved as new.js

```
$("#schoolpage").on("pageshow", function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

I have also tried

```
     $("#school").on("click", function(){
          alert("hello");
      });
```

But both don't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#schoolpage").on("tap", function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Does the above code solve your problem?